# c# handling cross country DateTime timezone

Tags: c#, sql-server, timezone

I am developing one application for dietitian. In this application dietitian can set diet for there customers anywhere in the world. Right now I am facing one issue about `MealTime` set by dietitian. Let's consider following example.

If dietitian is in India and set **Breakfast** meal time to `28/04/2021 09:00:00 AM`(IST). I store this value to `sql database` in GMT format(`28/04/2021 03:30:00 AM`). The customer is in Dubai then he is seeing **Breakfast** time to  `28/04/2021 07:30:00 AM` instead of **09:00:00 AM**.

what is the best way to handle this scenario ?

Comment: I would suggest to have the time zone info of the dietitian while setting the Mealtime (get the time zone form the client and store it in database). and then use that time zone info to manipulate the time while showing it to others

Comment: C# has very poor support for timezones.  It's why most developers use NodaTime instead of `DateTime`/`DateTimeOffset`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have stored dietitian Noda timezone  to db. like `Asia/Kolkata`

Comment: you can use momentjs library to manipulate/convert the time to a specific timezone. what technology are using for your client side?

Comment: @Annamalai what does the client-side matter? The dates are stored in the database and handled by the service

Comment: @Ajay IST means ... Israel Standard Time. Ireland Standard Time. India Standard Time. There are no standard timezone acronyms, so using them is meaningless. Neither DateTime or DateTimeOffset have any kind of *format* either, they're binary values. What you posted are just strings without any kind of timezone indicator

Comment: @Annamalai Flutter app send `UTC` time to api. Api store `DateTime` to `sql` database.

Comment: @Ajay don't store `datetime`. Don't send what you only assume is UTC.  If the timezone matters, *use the proper types*. That's `DateTimeOffset` in both C# and the database *at least*. Send the date as ISO8601, including either the offset or timezone from the client.

Comment: @Ajay UTC is no solution. What happens during summer time? What happens if two countries have different DST rules? What happens the next time Egypt or Russia decide to changes DST rules on short notice?

Comment: @Ajay - You haven't provided enough details.  Specifically, is the "dietitian" recording the actual time that the customer had breakfast (past or present)? Or are they setting up a future schedule for the customer's breakfast time (future)?  That matters here.  If future, is this the schedule for a specific date? Or is it the schedule for *every* day, or some other recurrence schedule?

Comment: @Powerlord - NodaTime is a great option, but your assertion about C# having poor support for time zones is incorrect - especially with regard to modern cross-platform .NET.

Comment: @Powerlord DateTimeOffset is the obvious answer, it has native support in both SQL Server and C#

Answer (score 1):

If you instead use `DateTimeOffset` to both store the time in the database *and* in your business domain logic, then the timezone information is available whenever you need it without having to join on a master reference to identify the correct timezone.

> In most application designs that involve queries and comparisons across multiple timezones `DateTimeOffset` can significantly simplify querying and reduce lookup logic to resolve the correct timezone. The major caveat is that your UI layer should pass through the original client data timezone or your data ingestion should sanitise or convert it when the data is written.

In both SQL and C# it is trivial to convert the values to different timezones when you need to, and these values will natively sort and filter correctly without having to cast them to specific zones.

Since SQL Server 2008 `DateTimeOffset` has been the guidance on for how to manage application data that spans across multiple timezones, in 2021 it should not be your first option any more.

Answer (score -2):

As I understand your question, you can save date time directly.

Eg. If you save `28/04/2021 09:00:00 AM` in database, your customers can see the same time no matter where he/she is.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I stored all datetime to db in `GMT` timezones.

Comment: @Ajay this means you lost the timezone information you needed. Using UTC time doesn't help. Using `datetimeoffset` is the absolute minimum if you care about timezones. Separately storing local time and the IANA timezone name is far better.

Comment: `28/04/2021 09:00:00 AM` is a local date *literal* stored in a localized format. There's no way to tell what actual time it represents without knowing what *country* it refers to. It's not even clear what month this format refers to: `07/04/2021 09:00:00 AM` would mean July 4th in the US, April 7th in the UK. And wouldn't work at all in Russia and Germany where the date separator is `.`